# How to bind a child list or array to datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am new to WPF and still trying to grasp the Binding aspect of WPF controls.  Let me first present the code that I am working with & then I'll pose the questions.

**CODE**

```
public class ScannedDocument : Csla.BusinessBase<ScannedDocument>
{
   private string _documentId = string.Empty;
   private BarcodeList _barcodeList = null;

   public string DocumentId
   {
      get { return _documentId; }
   }

   public BarcodeList Barcodes
   {
      get { return _barcodeList; }
      set 
      {
         if (_barcodeList.Equals(value))
         {
            _barcodeList = value;
            PropertyHasChanged("Barcodes");
         }
      }

   }
}

public class BarcodeList : Csla.BusinessListBase<BarcodeList, Barcode>
{
   public static BarcodeList NewBarcodeList()
   { return new BarcodeList(); }

   private BarcodeList() {}
}

public class Barcode : Csla.BusinessBase<Barcode>
{       
   public string Value
   { 
      get { return GetBarcodeValue(); }
   }

   public static Barcode NewBarcode()
   { return new Barcode(); }

   private Barcode() {}
}
```

**XAML**

```
<dg:DataGrid GridLinesVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="ScannedDocumentsListView">
<dg:DataGrid.Columns>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Document Name" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=DocumentId}"/>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Index 1" Width="80" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Barcodes[0].Value}" />
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Index 2" Width="80" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Barcodes[1].Value}" />
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Index 3" Width="80" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Barcodes[2].Value}" />
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Index 4" Width="80" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Barcodes[3].Value}" />
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Index 5" Width="80" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Barcodes[4].Value}" />
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Index 6" Width="80" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Barcodes[5].Value}" />
</dg:DataGrid.Columns>
```

**PROBLEM**

When I execute this code, I am able to bind the DocumentId successfully to the grid, but the barcode list doesn't seem to be binding correctly.  I have verified that there is data in the list.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual pattern to use in these cases is to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for your BarCode objects and expose them to the DataGridControl with a ObservableCollection. The DataGrid would then show one Barcode object per row with each column displaying the public properties of the BarCode.

Changes in either the Barcode or the the collection would then be propagated to the DataGrid and vice-versa (depending on the DataGrid properties).